# I feel very strongly about something meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

I want to know what the phrase in bold means.

> **I feel very strongly about** military service. I think everyone should do it.

Can you give me the substitute phrase that easy to understand? Is it like saying *I recommend you* or something?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feel%20strongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe emotionally, without being able to justify it fully with logic, that everybody should do military service.